# Wordpress Site Not Accessible over Domain Name

Tags: wordpress, redirect, apache2

My Wordpress(Woocommerce) site is hosted on AWS.
As long as my "Site URL" and "home" options are set to "http://3.143.13.125" and use http://3.143.13.125/wp-admin to login, it works.

Once I update the home and site URL to "http://delyvr.in" it stops working.

My Apache Site Config :

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
            ServerName delyvr.in
            ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
            DocumentRoot /var/www/wordpress
            ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
            CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
 <Directory /var/www/wordpress>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
```

my .htaccess file is :

```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

I always get a 302 in the apache access log:

```
172.31.19.145 - - [13/Apr/2021:05:05:50 +0000] "GET /wp-admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 372 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.82 Safari/537.36"
```

What am I missing here? Please help!

Comment: did you try to add WP_SITEURL and WP_HOME in wp-config.php ?

Comment: @GautamGolakiya no.. In the DB

Comment: Try to add it in the config file and check.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a DNS issue.
You need to go to your domain provider and set the DNS servers you're using there. Afterwards, in your DNS panel, you can add A/AAAA records that point to your URL, using your servers' IP address.

Additionally, make sure you're forcing https over http2. Adds value for google recognition and adds to your websites' security.

If you're trying to do this locally, however, all you need to do is add the following lines to your hosts file (C:\Program Files\Windows\system32\etc\hosts if I'm not mistaken)

delyvr.in 3.143.13.125 
[www.delvyr.in](http://www.delvyr.in) 3.143.13.125